# .htaccess rewrite folder, and set environmental params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, environment-variables

I would like to do a trick like this:

I have these folders

```
folder_dev
folder_live
```

and this code base:

```
folder
```

All folders are on the same level.

I would like to

1. redirect `folder_dev` to `folder` and set an environmental param THEME to 'dev'
2. redirect `folder_live` to the same `folder` but set an environmental param THEME to 'live'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the physical directories, you'll need a .htaccess file in each one, set up as follows:

In /folder/.htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf REDIRECT_THEME (.*) THEME=$1
```

In /folder_dev/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(?:folder_dev)
RewriteRule .* %1folder/$0 [E=THEME:dev]
```

In /folder_live/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(?:folder_live)
RewriteRule .* %1folder/$0 [E=THEME:live]
```

You need the SetEnvIf directive in the codebase folder because the environment variables set by mod_rewrite are always prefixed by REDIRECT_, which necessitates a final translation from REDIRECT_THEME to THEME.

You could also likely consolidate them into a single .htaccess file in the directory above (the fourth level in this case), allowing you to get rid of the folder_dev and folder_live directories if you didn't need them for another reason:

```
SetEnvIf REDIRECT_THEME (.*) THEME=$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder_dev/(.*)$ folder/$1 [E=THEME:dev]
RewriteRule ^folder_live/(.*)$ folder/$1 [E=THEME:live]

# Alternatively just:
# RewriteRule ^folder_([^/]+)/(.*)$ folder/$2 [E=THEME:$2]
```

Comment: There is a problem when looks for `/folder` that needs to relative from the current folder, and not from the domain root. This all will go in the 5th level of folder.

Comment: @Pentium10 I've updated both options to be more relative-path friendly now, hopefully that'll help.